# WPGraphQL - querying custom post types

Tags: wordpress, graphql, wp-graphql

How to query custom post types by custom taxonomy term? For example, I have custom post type “Courses” and custom taxonomies “City” and “Subject”. I want to query all courses that contain city: Warsaw and subject: excel.

In case of posts I can do it with categoryIn:

```
query MyQuery {
  posts(where: {categoryIn: [195, 1]}) {
    nodes {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a similar solution for custom post types?

Comment: just explore graphiql playground?

Comment: I tried but this is my first contact with graphql and I can't find a solution :(

Comment: CPT name should be (if properly configured for graphql) in the [explorer query] 'tree' like posts